# How to test a project using instrumentation test in android

Tags: android

I want to test my project using an instrumentation test. I am a beginner at this.

Can anybody provide a basic tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1):

Robotium is a great tool for testing Android app's you should take a look at it and it's very easy to use.
http://code.google.com/p/robotium/

Answer (score 0):

To use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 we can create a wrapper over it. In order to do so you can try out example that this blog talks about.
[testing Activities in simple way](http://garimasharma.github.com)

The idea used is to take out common code in wrapper called BaseActivityTest so that while testing you just need to do minimum steps, and your activity gets tested too.